# Extract lists from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list

Basically I have this:

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'c': 1}]
```

And I want an output like this:

```
new_list = [['a', 'b'],['c']]
```

I tried my own code but it just returns this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Please post your own code, and also specify your Python version (before 3.7 dictionaries were unordered).

Comment: `list(map(list, my_list))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = [list(d) for d in my_list]
```

It is basically equivalent to:

```
result = list(map(list, my_list))
```

Notice that using `list(d.keys())` is equivalent to `list(d)`.

As suggested by meowgoesthedog in a comment, be careful with Python versions older than 3.7: keys are not ordered, so you might end up having unsorted values.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it like -

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'c': 1}]

res = list(map(list,my_list))

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```

---

If you don't quite get how the above works, here's a simpler version to do the same -

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'c': 1}]

res = []
for dicts in my_list:
    res.append(list(dicts))    

# The above process is equivalent to the shorthand :
# res = [ list(dicts) for dicts in my_list ]

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
```